# how i filter a paragarph with this python code it works but just filter half of the words and left the rest and i don't know the reason

Tags: python

First I create empty DICTIONARY to count words in the paragraph and also variable for the paragraph

```
D={}
x="Wow, first off, a huge congrats. You're about to start the final project of the course. Amazing job making it all the way here. I hope you've been having as much fun as I have on this journey. We're going to be working on our final project using Jupyter notebooks. You might be starting to feel pretty confident using them. But remember if you have any issues you can always ask for help in the discussion forums. Okay, before we dive in, we're going to chat a little bit about what you'll be doing for the project, it's going to be really fun. The goal of the project is to create a word cloud. A word cloud is an image that's made up of different sized words. Usually the sizes of the words are determined by how many times each word appears in a specific text. To create the image itself, we're going to use an external Python module called creatively Word cloud. [LAUGH] Your job is to create a script that would go through the text and count how many times each word appears. We've done this a few times already, any ideas how we should tackle this one? If you're thinking of using a dictionary to count how many times each word appears, then. Ding ding ding, good answer! You're going to prepare a dictionary and use that as a parameter for the word cloud module, not too tricky, right? I think you can handle a little more, so two things you have to watch out for. One, punctuation marks, before counting the frequency of the words, you need to make sure that there are no punctuation marks in the text. If you don't, a string example with a comma at the end would be different from a string example with a dot at the end. So before you put words into the dictionary, you have to clean up the text to remove any punctuation marks. And the second thing we want to keep our word cloud interesting. Certain words in our language crop up a lot and if we include all of these we're going to get a pretty dull word cloud. Think about words like, the, two or if. They usually appear a whole lot in text but aren't too relevant to the text's overall message. We want our Cloud to show words that are relevant to the text we're using for the input. So you need to find a way to exclude irrelevant or uninteresting words when processing the text. For the input, you're going to upload a text file. You can choose any text file you like for your input. It could be the contents of a website, a full novel or even everything that one author has ever written. You just need to make sure that it's one text file, so that it can be processed by the code. Okay, before jumping into the project, remember you can re-watch this video If something isn't clear. Yep, I'm starting to sound like a broken record, but this time it's extra extra important. This final project is the real test of how much you've gotten your head around and can highlight areas you need to brush up on. So we want you to be super clear on what you need to do on that point. You'll find an overview of what you have to do in the next reading. Can you guess the best way of tackling this problem? Yep, you got it, our step-by-step approach that we outlined earlier. Understand the problem statement, research available options, plan your approach, write your code and finally execute. Okay, feeling good? Ready to go? Remember, you know this stuff and you've totally got it."
```

I want to filter out the words combined by these symbols

```
t= "!()-[]{};:\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'"
```

This is the first code i wrote it makes the paragraph a lowercase and split it to a list

```
b=x.lower()
y=b.split()
print(y)
```

this is the second code it filters the words with the symbols but
it filters just part of them unless I execute it few more times"

```
    for i in y:
      for o in range(len(t)):
        if t[o] in i:
            if i not in y:
                continue
            W=y.index(i)
            y.pop(W)
    #print(y)
    print(len(y))
```

These are the words i went to filter out after the symbols

```
uninteresting_words = ['a', "the", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
        "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
        "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
        "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
        "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]
```

this the code I wrote for it but this code also don't filter out all the words unless I execute it few times

```
    count=0
    for n in y:
        for n in uninteresting_words:
            h=y.index(n)
            count+=1
            y.pop(h)
    print(count)        
    #print(y)
    print(len(y))
```

this  the code that adds the words to the dic

```
  for words in y:
            D[words]=D.get(words,0)+1
  #print(D)
```

Comment: The reason is that you are modifying the list while you are iterating through it.  That causes the "pointer" to get confused.  A better plan is to create a new list containing only the words you want to keep, then delete the old list when you are done.

Comment: You're trying to generate a word cloud so you aren't supposed to remove words with punctionation, but rather remove the punctuation from the word. For your word cloud: "in, in" should be sized based on 2 "in"s not 1. Instead of excluding them entirely try to figure out how you could go about removing the values in `t` from your words.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem:

The problem is that `list.index` and `list.pop` only remove the first occurence of an item in a list

## Solution

Use list comprehensions instead:

### Replace

```
W=y.index(i)
y.pop(W)
```

and

```
h=y.index(n)
y.pop(h)
```

### With

```
y = [x for x in y if x != i]
```

and

```
y = [x for x in y if x != n]
```